# how to handle unformatted json while using @valid annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, microservices

I have a microservice written in springboot java 11. I have annotated the request with `@valid` to unsure its a valid format. However if the user send a request with body with is not even a correctly formatted json(say a comma is missing) then the request does not even reach the controller code and simply returns a `BAD REQUEST` status to user without any meaningful message. I would like the let the user know that the request is not a valid json. Can ideas how i can do this without over engineering it??

Comment: Isn't "BAD REQUEST" pretty much "your input (json) was invalid" already?

Comment: It isn't easy to understand what you are asking for.  Spring returns a 400 (bad request) if it cannot parse the JSON.  What is different about this case?

Comment: Check out [spring's blog on exception handling](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).  [Baeldung also has a decent tutorial on it as well](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring).